# Is it possible to generate a (compact) regular expression for an anagram of an arbitrary string?

Tags: regex, complexity-theory

Problem: write a program in any language which, given a string of characters, generates a regex that matches any anagram of the input string.  For all regexes greater than some length N, The regex must be shorter than the "brute force" solution listing all possible anagrams separated by "|", and the length of the regex should grow "slowly" as the input string grows (ideally linearly, but possibly n ln n).

Can you do it? I've tried, but my attempts are so far from succeeding, that I'm beginning to doubt it's possible.  The only reason I ask is I thought I had seen a solution on another site, but much pointless googling failed to uncover it a second time.

Comment: The length of the program won't change... don't you mean the length of the generated regular expression?

Comment: so basically you would get 2 strings of n letters and see if they contain exactly the same letters?

Comment: Yes, Mark - I meant the length of the regex.

Comment: yes - an anagram of "part" is "trap"  although in this case I'm not asking that the matches be restricted to words.  So given "panther", the resulting regex should match "hartpen".

Comment: No.  Let the string in question be "a".  It is not possible to produce a regular expression shorter than this that matches the string "a", ergo it is not possible to satisfy the requirements of the question. Actually, though, the question only makes sense if the regex only matches anagrams of the given string because the regex `.*` trivially matches all strings.

Comment: I can do it easily enough in Perl, but it won’t meet the length requirement.

Comment: For what it's worth, i did it in perl just for kicks.  :)  And though the expression starts out considerably longer than the search string, the length grows sub-linearly.  Once the expression gets over about 560 chars, it hardly grows at all.

Comment: Great question :) Python one-liner (because it otherwise won't fit in a comment; assuming that `a` is the input string): `>>> regex = "^(?:" + "|".join("{}()".format(c) for c in a) + "){{{}}}".format(len(a)) + "".join("\\{}".format(i+1) for i in range(len(a))) + "$"` :) Regex will grow linearly, but execution time (especially to find out a non-match) will grow exponentially.

Comment: So for `abc`, you get: `^(?:a()|b()|c()){3}\1\2\3$`

Comment: (And to be on the safe side, use `re.escape(c)` in the first `.format()` call)...

Comment: @Tim - thanks for your very elegant answer (or comment, whatever)!  Can you explain what the ()'s are doing after each of the letters?  Also - will your solution work for repeated letters?  Like loop <-> pool?

Comment: @cHao - do you want to post your solution?  vote to re-open the question!

Comment: @Mike: Yes it will. The `()` match the empty space (so they always succeed). Since they follow each letter, every single one has to be matched exactly once because at the end, we check that all backreferences have participated (`\1\2\3...`). Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607086/regular-expression-to-find-numbers-with-same-digits-in-different-order/1608789#1608789) for a better explanation. Sorry there isn't more room here, too bad this question was closed...

Comment: Yeah - I think I understand now. I did try this though: /^(?:a()|a()|b()|c()){4}\1\2\3\4$/  and it matched bbac? I can't see why.  This is w/ perl 5.8.8

Comment: @Mike: I removed my comment about bbac, because it was incorrect.  In my tests, ^(?:a()|a()|b()|c()){4}\1\2\3\4$ does actually *not* match bbac (with Python) but matches aabc, which is the intended behavior.  However, I'm not sure whether it is guaranteed that aabc should match, because this generalization of Tim's approach seems to require that the engine match the second `a` in the string with the second `a` in the (?:aa…) group (because of the `\1\2`).  In fact, I believe that aabc could in principle be matched by some regular expression engines with the *first* `a` *twice*.

Comment: yeah - it seems to be undefined which of the sub-expressions should match in a case like this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this javascript code will work according to your specifications. The regex length will increase linearly with the length of the input. It generates a regex which uses positive lookahead to match the anagram of the input string. The lookahead part of regex makes sure all the characters are present in the test input string ignoring their order and the matching part ensures that the length of the test input string is same as the length of the input string (for which regex is constructed).

```
function anagramRegexGenerator(input) {
    var lookaheadPart = '';
    var matchingPart = '^';
    var positiveLookaheadPrefix='(?=';
    var positiveLookaheadSuffix=')';
    var inputCharacterFrequencyMap = {}
    for ( var i = 0; i< input.length; i++ )
    {
        if (!inputCharacterFrequencyMap[input[i]]) {
            inputCharacterFrequencyMap[input[i]] = 1
        } else {
            ++inputCharacterFrequencyMap[input[i]];
        }
    }
    for ( var j in inputCharacterFrequencyMap) {
        lookaheadPart += positiveLookaheadPrefix;
        for (var k = 0; k< inputCharacterFrequencyMap[j]; k++) {
            lookaheadPart += '.*';
            if (j == ' ') {
                lookaheadPart += '\\s';
            } else {
                lookaheadPart += j;
            }
            matchingPart += '.';
        }
        lookaheadPart += positiveLookaheadSuffix;
    }
    matchingPart += '$';
    return lookaheadPart + matchingPart;
}
```

Sample input and output is the following

```
anagramRegexGenerator('aaadaaccc')
//generates the following string.
"(?=.*a.*a.*a.*a.*a)(?=.*d)(?=.*c.*c.*c)^.........$"
anagramRegexGenerator('abcdef ghij'); 
//generates the following string.
"(?=.*a)(?=.*b)(?=.*c)(?=.*d)(?=.*e)(?=.*f)(?=.*\s)(?=.*g)(?=.*h)(?=.*i)(?
=.*j)^...........$" 
//test run returns true
/(?=.*a)(?=.*b)(?=.*c)(?=.*d)(?=.*e)(?=.*f)(?=.*\s)(?=.*g)(?=.*h)(?=.*i)(?
=.*j)^...........$/.test('acdbefghij ')
//or using the RegExp object
//this returns true
new RegExp(anagramRegexGenerator('abcdef ghij')).test('acdbefghij ') 
//this returns false
new RegExp(anagramRegexGenerator('abcdef ghij')).test('acdbefghijj')
```

Comment: If you want to be more strict and allow only word characters and spaces in the input, you can just replace . with [\\w\\s] in the code.

Comment: This is interesting, but I don't think you've understood the requirements exactly.  In the case where there are repeated letters, the counts in the anagram must match exactly.  For example, I think your method will consider "ebb" and "bee" to be anagrams.  But I think a small variation on what you've done will work.

Comment: Oops, I missed this particular test case where letters are repeated. Fixed it now. Thanks for pointing out!